# How to pass GET Parameters in encrypt format in URL using Laravel form with GET Method?

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, laravel-5

I want to encrypt parameters when form submit. I am using laravel 5.2 version and when form submit that time I am using `get method` for submit the form. But when submit the form that time show all parameters in URL. So all this parameters I have to encrypt. For example

```
http://localhost:8000/get/experiences?category_id=18
```

to

```
http://localhost:8000/get/experiences/AQBBShSqt4zxsClTymwBhjIUP1kG7HEoqhoKMfAAlsMk2ZUOxStqGLAFFg0mM1nRKMEVVbB97xCvfRJTP0ZH3k1Am
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you use POST method?

Comment: I can't use post method because on url press enter show error Laravel 5 MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 201:

Comment: Please have a look once at this http://jenssegers.com/64/easy-id-obfuscation-with-laravel-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the route:

```
Route::post('/get/experiences/{category_id}', 'Controller@method');
```

After that you can make the form:

```
<form action="{{ url('/get/experiences/'.encrypt($category_id)) }}" method="post">
<!-- all your form data -->
<input type="submit" value="Post">
</form>
```

This will send a `POST` request to the route, `/get/experiences/{category_id}` and it will `encrypt` your `$category_id` using the `encrypt` method.

Hope this works!

Comment: I have more than ten parameters so how can add?

Comment: I suggest to post all those parameters instead of the url. @dhanashri

Answer (score 2):

Use `encrypt()` global helper to encrypt data and then `decrypt()` to decrypt it.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/encryption

Answer (score 0):

You can use post method. Add `Route::post('/get/experiences/{category_id}', 'Controller@method');` to your route and don't forget to add `{!! csrf_field() !!}` code within your form tags.

Parameters will not be shown in the URL so you will not have to do encryption. Of course, if you do not want to use the get method especially to encrypt.